# formatting a multiplication table with line spacing

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a multiplication table which is as big as the user specifies. The problem I'm having is with the format. The output right now prints all the numbers to one line, whereas I want it all on multiple lines on a nice neat table. With it formatted as it is, I can't tell where the `\n` would go to do so, or if there is another way.

here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class question2 {

  public static void main(String []  args) {

    Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0;

    while (i<=0 || i>=11) {
       System.out.print("please enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");
       i = keyb.nextInt();
    }

    for (int x = 1; x <= i; x++) {
       System.out.printf("%4d",x);
       for (int y = 1; y <= i; y++){
          System.out.printf("%4d",x*y);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The output for integer `5`, prints like this:

`1 1 2 3 4 5 2 2 4 6 8 10 3 3 6 9 12 15 4 4 8 12 16 20 5 5 10 15 20 25`

Comment: the output for integer 5, prints like this: 1   1   2   3   4   5   2   2   4   6   8  10   3   3   6   9  12  15   4   4   8  12  16  20   5   5  10  15  20  25

Comment: Would you please explain what is the use of `i` because it overwrites the old value every time. I guess you're looking for `Array` of `ArrayList`, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a newline after the second `for` loop, and since you print `x` don't print `x * 1`. So,

```
for (int x = 1; x <= i; x++) {
    System.out.printf("%4d", x);
    for (int y = 2; y <= i; y++) {
        System.out.printf("%4d", x * y);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**or** you could eliminate the first print like,

```
for (int x = 1; x <= i; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= i; y++) {
        System.out.printf("%-4d", x * y); // and simply for variety, left-aligned
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**or** if you are using Java 8+, you might use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) like

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i).forEachOrdered(x -> {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i).forEachOrdered(y -> System.out.printf(
                "%-4d", x * y));
    System.out.println();
});
```

Comment: That looks fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After the second for loop, add a new line `\n`:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= i; x++) {
    System.out.printf("%4d",x);
    for (int y = 1; y <= i; y++){
        System.out.printf("%4d",x*y);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println();`, or `System.out.printf("%n");`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. My screen only fits 14 numbers neatly. I make a list (it can house empty space `''`) and then I start to display the list neatly using the `end='\t'` argument keyword to create tabs.

```
n = int(input('Enter a number(max 14): '))
# n = 12

list_x = list(range(1,n + 1))
list_y = list(range(1,n + 1))
list_z = ['',] + list_x

for y in list_y:
    list_z.append(y)
    for x in list_x:
        x = x*y
        list_z.append(x)

count = 0

for i in list_z:
    print(i, end='\t')
    count += 1
    if count == (n + 1):
        count = 0
        print('', end='\n',)
```